# Cartthrob: Add discount amount to purchased items

Tags: cartthrob

I need to add a discount amount to each purchased item entry.  I had a conversation on Twitter that indicates that this is existing in CT already but is halfway there.  Has anyone accomplished this already?

Here is the twitter conversation I am referring to: https://twitter.com/cartthrob/status/388310009643159554

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do it:

1) Create a Discounts channel, and assign it in CartThrob

2) Create a Coupon Codes channel, and assign it in CartThrob

If you do the former, the discounts are automatically applied to each order.

If you do the latter, the user will have to enter a coupon code on the checkout form in order for the discount to happen.

You'll also need to put the HTML in place for the Coupon code to appear on the checkout form something like this:

```
                                <fieldset name="Coupon Code" class="control-group">
                                <div class="field-labels">
                                    <label for="coupon_code" class="clp">Coupon Code</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input id="coupon_code" class="field-bg clp" type="text" name="coupon_code" maxlength="31" />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
```